# Windows 10 activate window by mouse hover delay?

Tags: windows, configuration, mouseevent, mouseover

How can I modify the delay time? It currently has no delay and is so frustrating.

I've currently tried to modify

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Control Panel/Desktop/ActiveWndTrackTimeout

in `regedit`. Although I was able to modify it, it did not make any effect.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Rename your registry value from `ActiveWndTrackTimeout` to `ActiveWndTrkTimeout`.  Then sign out from Windows and sign in again.

It seems that this name changed in Windows 8.1.

I had this problem when I upgraded from Windows 8 to Windows 10, and after searching for a while, I eventually found the answer [on Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/664351/activewndtracktimeout-value-being-ignored), so do vote up over there if this helps you!

Also see the [Microsoft TechNet reference](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc957203.aspx).